# Execute jQuery only on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a button click on pageload with the piece of jQuery below

```js
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('#clickson').click();
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly but I have this button id on every page, how can I use it such that it only triggers on homepage and subdomain homepages.

For example it should only fire on example.com, subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com and **NOT** on any other pages like example.com/path, subdomain1.example.com/path, subdomain2.example.com/path

Comment: I suppose your pages content are being generated dynamically. So why don't just not include this script on pages where you don't need it? Thus - it is not jQuery related problem, rather it is concerned to generation of your pages.

Comment: The button is on sidebar and content are being generated dynamically, i added it on the page and it affects other contents generated by the same page

Comment: @user3476168 Tried checking `location.href` at `.ready()` event ?

Comment: @guest271314 i am not sure how to use this in the code below, i am not that good with jQuery, will appreciate if you give example

Comment: @user3476168 See post. Could check `location.href` for url of document , at `if` condition ; if url check returns `true` , call `.click()` on selected element

Comment: downvoted. i provided a working answer and you dissapeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking `location.href` for selected url

```
jQuery(function() {     
  var loc = location.href; 
  // if `location.href` is equal to  
  // "example.com","subdomain1.example.com", "subdomain2.example.com"
  // call `.click()` on `#clickson`
  if (loc === "example.com" 
      || loc === "subdomain1.example.com" 
      || loc === "subdomain2.example.com") {
    jQuery("#clickson").click();  
  }
});
```

```js
jQuery(function() {           
  if (location.href === "http://stacksnippets.net/js") {
    jQuery("#clickson")[0].click();  
  }
});
```

```css
#home {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a id="clickson" href="#home">click</a>
<div id="home">home</div>
```

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ _"I don't like hard-coded string approaches such as this. You also haven't catered for query string parameters. "_ ? Not certain how "don't like" relevant to Question or solutions provided by users ? No query strings were described at Question by OP. Only three urls without query strings

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you were against hardcoded string approaches, heres a simple bit of code that will accept an array of pages. `location.pathname` is the section of the url coming after the domain and before the query string. to my knowledge, it is implemented in every browser i have ever encountered.

```
var pages=['/','/home'];
for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++)
{
    if(location.pathname==pages[i])
    {
        //do stuff you want here
        break; //terminates the loop on first match
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex to match currect URL:

```
var href = window.location.href;
var regex = /(example\.com)$/i; // find only example.com at the end of URL

if ( regex.test(href) ){
  // if passed
  // do jQuery stuff here
}
```